# Is there a Windows equivalent to fallocate --punch-holes?

Tags: windows, ntfs, sparsefile

I'm looking for a way to punch holes in files on Windows such that the actual size-on-disk goes down, and the area that is punched gets deleted. Identical to the behavior of `fallocate --punch-holes` on Linux.

Does that exist? I know sparse files exist on NTFS so I believe it is theoretically possible.

Comment: There are similar operations in Windows OS for sparse files, depending on file system. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-file-operations